# Redirect http access of a program in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, http, redirection

My Eclipse is trying to contact fixed http urls (to get m2e connectors). These addresses are unavailable due to some proxy settings that I cannot change.

Is there a way to redirect the calls of Eclipse to some other address, i.e. is there a way to tell Windows 7 to redirect http accesses that programs try to make?

Comment: Do you want to redirect hostnames to other hostnames or would just redirecting to fixed IPs work?

Answer (score 2):

If you know the name of the server you can cancel them as the attached picture.

Create entries in the file **`C:\WINDOWS\System32\Drivers\Etc\hosts`**

In the example image, I redirected the address **www.google.com** to the IP of my own computer, **127.0.0.1**

In your case maybe you can replace www.google.com to the address you want to inhibit.

[image]